# Select a specific img tag in li tag

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm trying to add sprite images to the menu items in wordpress/ubermenu.
The custom class:

```
    #menu-item-4.sprite.icon-image a > img:first-child
   { background-position: -161px 0px!important; width: 22px; height: 22px;}
```

is applied to

> id="menu-item-4"

It should affect only the first image element, instead the style is applied to most images menu-item-4.
How to select this specific image?

```
<ul class="menu-id-1"> 
   <li id="menu-item-2">
      <ul class="submenu-id-3">
        <li id="menu-item-4" class="sprite icon-image">  <-- Costum CSS Class added here
          <a href="">
            <img>   <-- CSS to select this element only
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
          </a>
            <ul class="menu-submenu-id-5">
             <li id="menu-item-6">
               <a href="">
                 <img> <-- This element will have other icon
                 <span></span>
                 <span></span>
               </a>
             </li>
             <li d="menu-item-7">
               <a href="">
                 <img>
                 <span></span>
                 <span></span>
               </a>
             </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CSS selector selects all img-tags, that are directly a child of an a-tag inside your #menu-item-4.

try this:

```
    #menu-item-4 > a img
   { background-position: -161px 0px!important; width: 22px; height: 22px;}
```

Its probably better to add classes to a-tags or the img-tags

Comment: thank you, this worked like a charm! hours spent on this and i wouldn't have though of it. though i still not clear on why it works? select all images under A tag under Menu-item-4 - this would be also the other images as well, becouse they are also under A tag

Comment: the > selector only selects direct child elements. So only the first a-tag in your list. The other a-tags are all nested in an ul- or li-tag so they're not direct childs of #menu-item-4. Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `*:first-child` at the end. Your **`>`** selector is searching for the first image that appears inside your anchor and the `*:first-child` selector is confusing its path since there are no child elements for this image.

Your selector should be something like this:
`#menu-item-4.sprite.icon-image a > img`

This literally means - find and apply only to, the first image that you come across.

I suggest that you add a class to your anchor and simply address that.

e.g.

`#menu-item-4.sprite.icon-image .anchor-class > img`

Comment: #menu-item-4.sprite.icon-image a > img  this didn't work as it was applied to all other images under the tag falling within the rule.

Comment: That is regarding the code You provided, simply add a class to the anchor and the previous problem is gone.